# Xcode Project throws Error for requirement of macOS 11.0 or later

Tags: ios, xcode, version, macos-high-sierra

When I open MBP today and to see my project in Xcode, instead it opened older version (a month old at least). I search on Finder found the last version. However, when I try to open I am getting below error:

> You have macOS 10.13.2. The application requires macOS 11.0 or later.

Yesterday it was working fine. I installed Google Framework for AdMob and GoogleService plist. Is this could be the problem? Could it alter the project's requirement?

[image]

EDIT:

I am using latest macOS 10.13.2 and Xcode is latest Version 9.2 (9C40b).

Comment: There's no such thing as macOS 11.

Comment: @maddy I got screenshot of the error. I copy/pasted the error.

Comment: Could Xcode recognize iOS project as MacOS project? Somehow converted itself?

Comment: What is giving that error? Regardless, there is still no such thing as macOS 11.

Comment: When I try to open latest version of the project I am getting this error. Please see screenshot.

Comment: That message is from Finder and it means the compiled macOS app has been created incorrectly. Something in your project is setup to require a non-existent version of macOS.

Comment: I lost the latest version of the App I was working on. When I open, I got earlier version of the App and this compiled macOS with correct version. Is there a way to "uncompile" this macOS version and recover the iOS app?

Comment: No, you can't get back your source code from the compiled app. This is what Time Machine (or other backups) and source code control are for. Since you must be using at least one of those (right?), use it to get the desired version of your code.

Comment: I have archived previous versions inside the MBP. Also, I was doing testing on TestFlight. Is there a way I can recover from those?

Answer (score 1):

It looke like that xcode automatic updates are enabled and during the last shutDown/start the version updated and requires high macOSX version than the current , check xcode version and google the least system requirements for it